# How can I fill search form with checkboxed by search get-parameters in Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel

I make products filter in ecommerce website using Laravel.

```
I have this url localhost:3000/?category=tops&color=black
```

I need fill checkboxes by "checked" in my filter search form like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('layouts.main') }}" method="GET">

<h4>Category</h4>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" name="category[]" value="tops">
    Tops
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="bottoms">
    Bottoms
</label>

<h4>Color</h4>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" name="category[]" value="black">
    Black
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="white">
    White
</label>

</form>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puts all your categories on Array or Collection (e.g `Category::all()` ) and process this way

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
   <label>
     <input {{ in_array(strtolower($category->name), Request::get('categories')) ? 
     'checked="checked"':
     '' }} 
     type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="{{ strtolower($category->name) }}">
     {{ $category->name }}
   </label>
@endforeach
```